# jQuery .css() function with variables and multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, syntax

Weird little snafu. I'm using jQuery's `.css()` method to change the size of text (long story; no, I can't use media queries) using a variable and I need to add `em` to it. I'm not sure what the syntax is because there are multiple values for the CSS change.

To illustrate:

This works perfectly. It adds `em` to the calculated value of `victore`:

```
$('h1').css('font-size', victore + 'em');
```

This doesn't:

```
$('h1').css({
    'font-size':victore + 'em',
    'line-height':vignelli + 'em';
});
```

The `em` needs quotes... but so does the value. Wrapping it in parens didn't work

Comment: On your most recent edit you need to remove the `;` after the last `em`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You shouldn't have the quotes around the whole thing:

```
$('h1').css({
    'font-size': victore + "em",
    'color':'red'
});
```

Comment: gotcha. made a mistake when I copied over my code. see above edit.. it breaks my code.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, you now have a semicolon that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

The font-size value is required to be a string, but that string can be the result of an expression, in your case `victore + 'em'` should result in the appropriate string.

```
$('h1').css({ 
    'font-size': victore + 'em', 
    'color': 'red' 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPEVs/).

```
$('h1').css({
    'font-size':victore + "em",
    'color':'red'
});
```

Comment: Ah I see. I made a mistake when I copied the code over.. Please see edited post for a different example of what doesn't work. Tried it in your fiddle and no dice

Comment: @technopeasant, see the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPEVs/1/).  I used pixels instead of ems for the example.  EDIT: Here's a version with `em`: http://jsfiddle.net/sPEVs/2/