# Passing variables with jquery css function doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Im trying to make a grid-layout work in IE10 and am very close to the solution (at least I think so). I wrote this short script which should do the trick telling the div's in which way to be placed in the grid, since apparently IE can't autofill.

```
var x = 1;
var y = 1;
jQuery(".grid .flex").each(function () {
        jQuery(this).css('-ms-grid-row', x);
        jQuery(this).css('-ms-grid-column', y);
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);
        if (y >= 3) {
            y = 1;
            x++;
        }
        else {
            y++;
        }
});
```

The right values for the div's are put out on console, but it seems that the .css() function does not quite get that they are just numbers. I does not work the way it is shown here, but when I change the method to *"-ms-grid-row**s**(or -column**s**)"* the script injects the style-tag just fine.

I think that jquery assumes the variables are pixel-measurements which would explain why *"-ms-grid-rows"* works and *"-ms-grid-row"* doesn't.

Is there a way to fix this? Can I tell explicitly that the variables are just numbers?

Sry if this all sounds a bit messy i'm just an intern trying to solve a problem because the senior developer is on vacation. Also im just a rookie with "web-development".

Comment: `jQuery(this).css({'-ms-grid-row': x,'-ms-grid-column': y});`

Comment: Maybe try `jQuery(this).css('-ms-grid-row', String(x));` or even `jQuery(this).css('-ms-grid-row', ''+x);` to explicitly cast as a string (I honestly can't say if this will work, it depends what jQuery does with it after you've passed it in, but if it's testing for either a number or a string and then doing different things based on that, it might help).

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I think it might do the trick:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462040/jquery-css-function-with-variables-and-multiple-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 jQuery(this).css('-ms-grid-row', x.toString())
```

Comment: Detailed explanation from the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) "When a **number** is **passed as the value**, jQuery will convert it to a string and **add px** to the end of that string. If the property requires units other than px, convert the value to a string and add the appropriate units before calling the method."