# How to set the background and font color of a table cell in HTML5 using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically set the background and font color of a table cell in HTML5 using jquery. I have tried:

```
$('td.T1', row).css('background-color', '#DC291E', 'color', '#FFFFFF');
```

This only sets the background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an object:

```
$('td.T1', row).css({'background-color': '#DC291E', 'color': '#FFFFFF'});
```

Comment: @RobKwasowsky: It was not an error per se (and anyway we can all make mistakes), I did the comment on your old post just to clarify for others being sure you already know, not for any discussion or bad criticism. But couldn't resisted to write it again once I saw you deleted for my comment. Anyway all good and happy coding man!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your syntax is incorrect, you should fix like this

```js
$('div').css({'background-color': '#DC291E', 
                         'color': '#FFFFFF'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Content</div>
```

Hopefully, this post was helpful for you

[jQuery .css() function with variables and multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462040/jquery-css-function-with-variables-and-multiple-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Glyn